# Batch file to create folder and move file in the folder

Tags: batch-file

I am in the middle of batch extracting screenshots for contents we are planning to use on a tube site I am working on.

The jpeg files per content is labled as followed:

```
6c82c0239f6eb839-1
6c82c0239f6eb839-2
all the way to 120
```

The file name is different per content

```
a82384e2c46ba4af-1
a82384e2c46ba4af-2
etc.
```

They will all be extracted to a singe folder.

So I basically need a batch file that will create folders based on the content name without the dash and number and move all 120 jpegs in the folder with the content name.

For example:
Create folder named 6c82c0239f6eb839 and
move 6c82c0239f6eb839-1 to 6c82c0239f6eb839-120 in to the created folder.

I saw another thread with the following batch file. its pretty much what I want but the folder name is only 3 characters long and the files are copied to the newly created folders instead of moving them.

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.jpeg') do (
  set Name=%%a
  set Folder=!Name:~0,3!
  xcopy  /y "%%a" !Folder!\
)
```

Could someone change this so that it will display full file name without the dash and number for the folders and move files in its respective folders instead of copy?

Thank you

Comment: So why do you think the folder name is only three characters long?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. Im guessing its the !Name:~0,3! area right? Sorry, im a total beginner and have no idea what im doing please bear with me.

Comment: *Could someone change this* I'm afraid that's not how this site works. We're not a custom programming service that writes code to meet your requirements for you. Make an effort to understand what the code is doing and try to change it yourself.

Comment: You're right, I will dig around on my end too

Comment: I absolutely do not get what you mean by *the jpeg files per content is labled as followed* and *the file name is different per content*; please explain. Also share your own efforts. Read the [tour] and learn [ask] here; also consult this: [mcve]

Comment: Microsoft definitely needs to promote their `forfiles` feature more :-)

Comment: @Dominique , definitely not needed to accomplish this task, nor do I think it could accomplish this task. You would still need a FOR /F command to split the file name apart. Also FORFILES would be more overhead because you have to start a cmd.exe instance for each file it has to process.

Comment: @aschipfl Hi, Thank you for the heads up. I'm sorry, I did not mean to disrespect the community by all means. And yes, you're right. I need to work on being able to efficiently explain my issues. I will make sure to review the code of conduct and other rules and manners for this website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

@rem Get each jpeg file.
for /F "delims=" %%A in ('2^>nul dir /b *.jpeg') do (

    rem Get filename as token before the dash.
    for /f "delims=-" %%B in ("%%~A") do (

        rem Make dir if needed.
        if not exist "%%~B" md "%%~B"

        rem Check if isdir.
        2>nul pushd "%%~B" && popd

        if errorlevel 1 (
            >&2 echo Failed isdir "%%~B".
        ) else (

            rem Do the move operation.
            >nul move /y "%%~A" "%%~B"

            if errorlevel 1 (
                >&2 echo Failed move "%%~A" to "%%~B"
            )
        )
    )
)

exit /b %errorlevel%
```

The code is well remarked so if you want to understand
the evaluated code by changing `@echo off` to `@echo on`.
The use of `%errorlevel%` after the `exit /b` is not
required though will let you know what the `errorlevel` is
when `@echo on` is used.

The `pushd` tests for a directory
(even if it is a symlink).
`errorlevel` is checked to decide if to echo a
error message or do the `move`.

As the `for` loop variables are used direct, use of
`enabledelayedexpansion` is not needed.

Many commands support the argument of `/?` to get help
about the command. i.e. `move /?`.

Comment: It's much easier to check the attribute of a meta variable if it contains the letter d for directory than using a subroutine `echo %%~aB|findstr "d" >Nul 2>&1 && (>nul move /y "%%~A" "%%~B")`

Comment: I am not understanding why you are doing a directory check. The question clearly states that the directory needs to be created.

Comment: @LotPings, easier is opinion. Running `findstr` within a loop is inefficient as it is an executable that may need to run with each loop cycle. I would rather use internal commands which have less overhead.

Comment: @Squashman, the directory check is done in case a filename of the same name exists to avoid overwrite by `move` later. Overwriting a file that is supposed to be a directory 120+ times, using `move`, is not a good experience.

Comment: @michael_heath, I follow your logic on that. I will offer an alternative option on the `ISDIR`.  You could replace your `CALL` to your `ISDIR` function with `dir /a-d "%%~B" >nul 2>&1`. Then change the comparison to `IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1`

Comment: @Squashman, `errorlevel` changes after the first file is copied. `dir /a-d "%%~B" >nul 2>&1` is checking inside the directory for files rather than the argument as being a folder or a file.

Comment: @michael_heath Hello, thank you for your reply.  This worked properly for my situation. Thank you very much.  I will try to take what Squashman is sharing too and mess around with it for fun on the side.

Comment: I moved `pushd` into the loop so the concern of `call` of the label is obsolete. @inazma, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you only try to copy the correct `jpeg` to the correct folder, you can do this:

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
CD <CORRECT ROOT PATH>
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.jpeg') do (
  set Name=%%a
  REM I presume all the files have 16 characters before the dash
  set Folder=!Name:~0,16!
  IF NOT EXIST !Folder! MKDIR !FOLDER!
xcopy  /y "%%a" !Folder!\
)
```

I was not able to test.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply.  `CD <C:\Users\sfb11\OneDrive\Desktop\image>` would this be the correct way to input the correct root path?  I tried adding pause at the very end to see why its not doing anything, but I haven't been able to see why its not working.

Comment: @inazma That would be two commands: `c:` and on the next line `CD \Users\sfb11\onedrive\desktop\image`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to apologize for my manners regarding my initial post.

The answer by micheal_heath has resolved my issue.

Furthermore, I happened to find this post by user Salmon Trout from a different site which also worked.

[Batch file to make folders with part of file name and then copy files](https://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=152980.0)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%A in (*.psd *.jpg) do (
   echo file found  %%A
   for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do set fname=%%~nB
   for /f "delims=" %%C in ("%%A") do set fextn=%%~xC
   for /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %%D in ("!fname!") do set folname=%%D
   echo folder name !folname!
   if not exist "!folname!" (
      echo Folder !folname! does not exist, creating
      md "!folname!"
   ) else (
      echo Folder !folname! exists
   )
   echo Moving file %%A to folder !folname!
   move "%%A" "!folname!"
   )
echo Finished
pause
```

I just changed the the following line remove the hypen and numbers to create folders for the file name properly.

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=-***" %%D in ("!fname!") do set folname=%%D
```

I still lack the knowledge on why and how both methods work, but this has been an interesting start for me. I hope other beginners trying to solve a similar issue can find something useful from this post.

Comment: Option `tokens=1*` is get 1st token and get remainder as 2nd token. You only need the 1st token before the dash. Use `delims=-` as `tokens=1` is a default option and you do not need the remainder. View `for /?` for help.

Comment: When working with batch files I use [ss64.com](http://www.ss64.com) very often as reference document.